# Convert Arbitrary Datatype to String in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

How do you convert an variable of arbitrary datatype to a string in Matlab? That is, I'd like to have a function that produces a string so I can concatenate it and do other operations without knowing the datatype beforehand.

For classes and other non-primitive datatypes, something like what disp() outputs would work fine, but I don't know how to capture the output for disp().

I'd like to be able to do this without having to detect datatypes and then call each xyz2str.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can capture the output of `disp` using `evalc`:

```
any2str = @(x) evalc('disp(x)');

any2str(3)
any2str(eye(3))
any2str({'hello', 'world'})
any2str(struct('Name', 'Sarah', 'Age', 23))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can now use

```
jsonencode(obj)
```

See https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html

Comment: Please don’t post the same answer in multiple questions. If multiple questions accept the exact same answer, you could flag them as duplicates.